# Render Devise Edit as Partial View in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am currently developing a rails app. I have installed the devise gem and generated its view. I have a page as 'my profile' which allows the signed in user to edit the details that was entered on sign up. However, i want to render `devise/registrations/edit` inside tabs that i have created using bootstrap in my profile page.

Currently my profile page looks something like this.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" 
    aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  //
  //
  //**This is where I want to add the registrations/edit from devise.**
  // 
  //
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it using the following snipppet:

```
<%= render template: "devise/registrations/edit" %>
```

So your template becomes:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#" role="tab" 
    aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="true">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
  //
  //
  //**This is where I want to add the registrations/edit from devise.**
  <%= render template: "devise/registrations/edit" %>
  // 
  //
  </div>
</div>
```